# UITableView not able to fetch data from array

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, nsmutablearray

i am making iPad application, in which i am fetching data from Url, after fetching data from URL,

i am storing into array,

when i write NSLOG inside this two TableView method,

it works properly,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLOG(@"ARRAY=%@",arrayname);
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section     {
NSLOG(@"ARRAY=%@",arrayname);
}
```

but when i write this NSLOG inside this method thn it shows error,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLOG(@"ARRAY=%@",arrayname);
    }
```

i also declared nsmutablearray properly....

it shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS

**why this any idea ?**

Comment: Xcode should issue warnings for those delegate methods, since you're not returning what you should. But you're probably overreleasing the array. Check the lifetime of your array and make it doesn't die before the table view does. Otherwise, your table view delegate methods are trying to access an object that no longer exists. Maybe post code relevant to your array, as part of your question.

Comment: where you are creating this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method cellForRowAtIndexPath *must* return the cell, otherwise you'll see the error you see. But if the code above is 'metacode', and you put you NSLog somwhere between the proper strings of code, then you can follow Alex Reynolds' advice.

Check if your array is still alive. E.g. you can set a breakpoint and check if the program falls because of turning to 'arrayname', and if so, try to find where it could be released in your code by this moment. Also, perhaps you're just create your array with wrongly.